# How to get FaultException details?

Tags: list, exception, services

I am getting exception as below while updating list column:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   ListServiceReference.ListsSoap.UpdateListItems(UpdateListItemsRequest
>   request)

Do not know what exactly going wrong? 
Is there any way to get more details from faultexception? 
I have tried using

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
```

in web.config file, but did not worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following code to get more details about fault exception.

```
    catch (FaultException fe)
    {
         MessageFault msgFault = fe.CreateMessageFault();
         XmlElement elm = msgFault.GetDetail<XmlElement>();
         var exceptionDetails = elm.InnerText;
    }
```